# Laravel Global Scopes : ErrorException Undefined property: App\Models\User::$company

Tags: laravel

I am working on a multi company application and I want to filter the data based on which type of user is logged in .. [ Head Office Admin or Standard User ]

So I want head office to be able to see all branch companies reports, so in the head office company profile, I auto generated a code on registration. So all branches registered after need that code so they are linked up to head office.

This is the error I get.

```
ErrorException
Undefined property: App\Models\User::$company
```

I want to setup a global scope so head office admin can access branch companies, including data.

*/ Company Model Global Scope /*

```
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        if(Auth::user()->user_role_id >= 4 && Auth::user()->access_hq == 'YES'){
            static::addGlobalScope('hq_code', function (Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where('hq_code', Auth::user()->company['hq_code']);
            });
        } elseif(Auth::user()->user_role_id >= 4 && Auth::user()->access_hq !== 'YES'){
            static::addGlobalScope('id', function (Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where('id', Auth::user()->company_id);
            });
        }
    }
```

*/ Model Relationships /*

```
/**
* User Model
*/
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Company::class);
    }

/**
* Company Model
*/

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\User::class);
    }
```

**EDIT**

If I debug the query logged in as Admin/HQ Admin I still get the error, but when I am logged in as branch user/standard user I get this

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1955 ▼
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#1962 ▶}
  #model: App\Models\Company {#1948 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: array:4 [▶]
  #onDelete: Closure(Builder $builder) {#1944 ▶}
  #passthru: array:19 [▶]
  #scopes: array:2 [▼
    "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope {#1765 …}
    "id" => Closure(Builder $builder) {#1854 ▼
      class: "App\Models\Company"
      file: "DRIVE:\webapp\app\Models\Company.php"
      line: "70 to 72"
    }
  ]
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

**Edit - dd(auth()->user())**

```
App\Models\User {#1938 ▼
  #fillable: array:4 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #attributes: array:17 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "users"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #original: array:17 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

Comment: Is this line throwing you the error ? `$builder->where('hq_code', Auth::user()->company['hq_code']);` Did you try to debug it

Comment: Yes, its throwing an error and I did debug it its still giving me the same error when logged in as HQ Admin but if I am logged in as standard user or branch user I get the data filtered

Comment: I think it's because `Auth::user()->company` needs to **boot** `Company` when it call `->company` but isn't booted yet since we are **in** the boot. Does it makes sense?

Comment: So its trying to boot the company model and on the same token trying to filter the company model which is not booted ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _token_ but if we understood each other correctly this is exactly this. To be more precise; The scope added in `addGlobalScope` will be played before we can load any relationship `->company`. Which means the attribute `$company` does not exists yet. I don't have a solution to your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best implementation here but what I am thinking of doing is to add a column in users table with hq_code , on registration of  HQ Admin User I take hq_code and add it there on the user profile.

For the standard users I will have default code for consistency.

I've done tests already with local demo db I am achieving the results of having all branches with the head office displayed in the list of companies.

So I am not sure if this solution is the best, but it works for what I need at the moment.

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    if (Auth::user()->user_role_id >= 4 && Auth::user()->access_hq == 'YES') {
        static::addGlobalScope('hq_code', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('hq_code', Auth::user()->hq_code);
        });
    } elseif (Auth::user()->user_role_id >= 4 && Auth::user()->access_hq !== 'YES') {
        static::addGlobalScope('id', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('id', Auth::user()->company_id);
        });
    }
}
```

---

##### EDIT:

I think I will have to add the same HQ Code as well to standard users so that the HQ Admin can have access or be able to see all users who belong in the same hq_code.

The branch office admin can access users that belong in the same company using the company_id column.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here, you are trying to access to your defined relationship but is wrong sintax

```
Auth::user()->company['hq_code']
```

must be

```
Auth::user()->company->hq_code
```

Comment: Hi, still its giving me an error 
`ErrorException
Undefined property: App\Models\User::$company`

Comment: @BonganiDlamini well it's a good thing that error changed, means it worked. Can you `dd(auth()->user());`